# deleting some items from a child collection in ef core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a parent table and child table, where the parent has a one-to-many relationship with the children.

I want to delete some of the children and I want the parent's child collection to reflect that change.

If I delete the selected children using `RemoveRange`, then the child collection doesn't get updated.  If I use `Remove` to remove the children from the child collection then (apparently) it's not as efficient as using `RemoveRange`.

So I have to use `RemoveRange` to delete the children efficiently and then use `Remove` to remove them from the child collection.  Is this correct or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: I can't believe no one has answered this yet. The problem of being on the bleeding edge is there aren't enough experts out there yet.

Answer (score 0):

With `RemoveRange`, where you will save time is in the overhead around removing the objects from the child collection, especially around change tracking which will run once rather than once for each object with `Remove`.

Either way, you will only make one trip to the database when you call `SaveChanges`.

So, in your example, `RemoveRange` is redundant and can be omitted.